# For views, how do I display only one of a series with the same title?

Tags: views

We have a view that displays upcoming events. We use civiCRM for events. Some of our events are ongoing: they have the same title, but different dates. What logic could I use to display the next upcoming event, without displaying all upcoming events?

For instance, at the moment the events displayed are based on date. Any event that is not yet passed will display in the view. But for a class which meets 10 times, I do not want 10 of the same title, just the next class and its date/time.

Answer (score 0):

To only show one immediate next upcoming event:

1. add **Sort criteria** by date (ascending so you get the events that are soonest to happen as first on the list), make sure the correct one come up top
2. and then limit your results to only show 1 row (**Display a specified number of items** to 1 under Pager options, but don't output the Pager).